# Can someone please tell me how to make a title center?

Tags: titles

This is my title.

```
\title{"IT" gas station Finder \newline Windows Mobile Application \newline \newline  PROJECT REPORT\newline \newline}%
```

This is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\title{"IT" gas station Finder \newline Windows Mobile Application \newline \newline  PROJECT REPORT\newline \newline 
Presented to
The Faculty of Computer Sciences \newline UOM \newline \newline 
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{sablogo} \newline \newline 
\begin{center}
 In Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the degree
\end{center}
Computing and Information Systems} 


\date{\today} 

\begin{document}
% there are some things
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you intend to use \title, you need \maketitle to show it.  However, you don't HAVE to use \title, \author etc.

Comment: @user54172: I agree with John Kormylo: It is better to drop the `\maketitle` and other `\title` command, they are somehow weird ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not the ideal example, but one can work with it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}% 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }%

\title{%
\begin{center}
"IT" gas station Finder\\
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
Windows Mobile Application\\
\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
PROJECT REPORT\\
\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
Presented to\\
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
The Faculty of Computer Sciences\\
\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
UOM\\
\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{sablogo}\\
In Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the degree
Computing and Information Systems
\date{\today} 
\end{center}%
}% End of Title



\begin{document}
\maketitle%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user54172: Please do not forget to accept one of the provided solutions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems easier to do it by hand. Start from the code below and add font selection and vertical space as desired.

```
\begin{document}

\titlepage
\centering

"IT" gas station Finder

Windows Mobile Application

PROJECT REPORT

Presented to The Faculty of Computer Sciences

UOM

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{sablogo}

In Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the degree

Computing and Information Systems

\today

\newpage
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the \title-command, you can use something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begingroup
{\huge "IT" gas station Finder \\ Windows Mobile Application}\par
\vspace*{18pt}
{\Large PROJEKT REPORT}\par
\vspace*{18pt}
{\large Presented to \\
The Faculty of Computer Sciences \\ UOM}\par
\vspace*{12pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{sablogo} \par
\vspace*{12pt}
{\large In Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the degree \\ Computing and Information Systems}\par
\vspace*{12pt}
\today
\endgroup
\end{center}

\end{document}
```